# eth says I have a balance of 35 ether - etherchain can't find my address

Tags: ethereum

In the ethconsole I get the following:

```
> web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.coinbase), "ether")
35'
```

When I run `web3.eth.coinbase` and enter the resulting `0x00f24...` address into https://www.etherchain.org/ , I get `Error: Account '0x00f24...' not found!`.

How do I independently verify my balance? Is my `coinbase` address my wallet address? Or do I have a different address where the ether is residing?

Comment: I have a similar issue, where i cannot verify my eth balance on Etherchain.org, similar to your case it cannot find the address i search for (only have that single address, from Poloniex, if of importance). I am quite new to this, so might be i am missing some basic information, but thought i'd add on to this, since unanswered for 2 months seemingly.

Comment: @TobiasKJ: You might want to try asking on the new [Ethereum](http://Ethereum.stackexchange.com).SE.

Comment: you are probably not up to date